# How to get the elementByClassName of another element

Tags: javascript

How can I get the elementByClassName of another element? (trying to get `title` and `author`)

#### HTML

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="title">Title 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="author">Author 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript

My code gets a list of `posts`:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
```

How can I get the `title` and `author` assuming I can't just create two lists of classes.

```
list.getElementsByClassName("top").getElementsByClassName("title");
```

^^ This does not work because `list` is an element.

Comment: _“This does not work because `list` is an element”_ – no, it is an HTMLCollection. And therefor you have to access the elements within that collection individually via index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This does not work because list is an element.

No, if `list` were an element, it *would* work. It doesn't work because `list` is a *collection* of elements.

`list[0]` is an element:

```
list[0].getElementsByClassName("top")
```

But I would recommend using `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` insetad, which let you use the full range of CSS selectors (and work even on IE8, which doesn't have `getElementsByClassName`).

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".post");
```

For instance, this lists the `title` and `author` of every post:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".post")).forEach(function(post) {
    var title = post.querySelector(".title").innerHTML;
    var author = post.querySelector(".author").innerHTML;
    // ...
});
```

(`Array.from` is an ES2015 thing, but can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill). `Array#forEach` is an ES5 thing, but can be polyfilled for truly obsolete browsers like IE8 if necessary.)

Comment: Never heard of `Array.from`. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the elements in the HTMLCollection returned by `getElementsByClassName`, call `getElementsByClassName` on each and push the results to an array.

```
var elements = [];
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("post"), function(el) {
  [].push.apply(elements, el.getElementsByClassName("title"));
  [].push.apply(elements, el.getElementsByClassName("author"));
});
```

But better use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".post .title, .post .author");
```